# Java Improving code efficiently

Tags: java, performance, math

Ive used the following function in one of my programs.

I have tried to make sure that my code is efficient however I cannot find any help online to tell me how to recognize where I could improve...

Is there any one that can help identify if there are any parts of this where I could improve (make faster) or run more efficiently

z, s and t are all integers

```
powerMod(z, s, t) {
    int temp = 1;
    while (s > 0) {
        temp = temp * z;
        s = s - 1;
    }
    temp = temp mod t;
    return temp;
}
```

so the overall function of this is too calculate z to the power of s then mod it by n every time. very simple yet I cannot figure out how i can make this faster as it will be used by main program 100s or 1000s of times

Comment: Rule of thumb: do not delve into performance matters unless you have an actual performance problem. Especially with Java, since the JIT is there for you, and is smarter than you.

Comment: This should probably be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [exponent by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Comment: in my opinion this is rather a mathematical problem to find an algorithm that requires less computational steps than optimization of code base. @amit has already given a hint

Comment: Also, while mathematically `(x*x*x*...*x mod t) == (x mod t)*(x mod t)*...*(x mod t)`, this is not the case with integers that might overflow.

Comment: changing this to a recursion method may be faster? what do you all think?

Comment: Again: why do you _care_? Do you have an _actual performance problem_? If this code works for you, just stick with it. "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Comment: @fge reason is im going to be running this for hours, need it to be as fast as possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so something like this?

using the [exponentiation by square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) and ive used long just in case of overflow due to int * int...

```
 int powMod(int z, int s, int t){
        long result = 1; //int * int will never exceed the size of a long
        long multiplicant = z;
        while(s > 0){
            if(s % 2 == 1) {
                result *= multiplicant;
                result %= t; // do modulo on each temporary result to keep accuracy
            }

            multiplicant *= multiplicant;
            multiplicant %= t;
            s /= 2;

        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: @amit what do you think of the above?

Answer (score 1):

First, note that your code will fail to do what you description asks to do for large inputs:

> ...so the overall function of this is too calculate z to the power of
>   s then mod it by n every time. ...

However, note that your code will break for large values due to [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), since you will first try to calculate a huge number, which is likely to overflow - and only then you will invoke the mode operator.

The correct way to calculate the above is using the fact that:

```
(x*x*x*...*x) mod t == (...(((x mod t)*x) mod t)*...*x) mod t
```

The second calculation will yield the correct answer for much larger inputs, only assumption needed is `x*t <= Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is a much simpler assumption.

As for your request to improve performance - the power operator is efficiently calculated using [exponent by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Make sure you utilize the above equation in this method as well to avoid mistakes for large inputs.

Another solution is to use java's BigInteger library, specifically the method [`BigInteger.modPow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow(java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger))

Comment: Same as the OP code, this code will break if some assumptions are not considered.

Comment: @Andres The required assumption to make this code break is much less significant, and is addressed easily (multiply using `long`s, not `int`s).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building your own operator, try using `Math.pow()` (and add the mod part).

Comment: Similar to the OPs code, this will break (in a different way - but still) for large values.

Comment: @amit as far as I understand, any incremental operation will eventually break for large enough values.

Comment: No. Since `(x*x*x*...*x mod t) == (x mod t)*(x mod t)*...*(x mod t)`, and assuming `x^2 < Integer.MAX_VALUE` (much simpler assumption then x^s is in range) - the later is guaranteed to provide the correct results.

Comment: because math.pow() is not as accurate and ive always been told to stay off it.

Comment: @mirak yeap, (And in general - stay away from `double`s unless you know exactly what you're doing, since they are all inaccurate).

Comment: @amit isn't the whole point of programming that you should only do things when you know what you're doing? there's nothing magic about doubles in that respect

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt There is. They don't behave as you expect them to. Many programmers expect `double`s to perform like real numbers, and neglect the rounding error they introduce to fit the floating point format. This causes huge mistakes when later you repeat this operation a lot of times.  The post [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a must to anyone dealing with `double`s and `float`s.

Comment: @amit that's what I mean. there's something special about everything. some people don't realize that an `int` has a limited range either. and in any case, there are many circumstances in which you can use doubles without worrying much about it, such as in graphics programming, where numbers are always within a reasonable range.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Math?  Seems like the fastest way to me.

```
powerMod(double z, double s, double t)
{
    double a = Math.pow(z, s);
    return Math.floorMod(a, t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are **really** concerned by performance you can use [Guava.IntMath.pow()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html#pow(int,%20int)) which does exponentiate in O(log(n)) time. Source code of this implementation is below:

```
public static int pow(int b, int k) {
    checkNonNegative("exponent", k);
    switch (b) {
      case 0:
        return (k == 0) ? 1 : 0;
      case 1:
        return 1;
      case (-1):
        return ((k & 1) == 0) ? 1 : -1;
      case 2:
        return (k < Integer.SIZE) ? (1 << k) : 0;
      case (-2):
        if (k < Integer.SIZE) {
          return ((k & 1) == 0) ? (1 << k) : -(1 << k);
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      default:
        // continue below to handle the general case
    }
    for (int accum = 1;; k >>= 1) {
      switch (k) {
        case 0:
          return accum;
        case 1:
          return b * accum;
        default:
          accum *= ((k & 1) == 0) ? 1 : b;
          b *= b;
      }
    }
  }
```

You should also note that in most practical cases regular `Math.pow()` will be enough for your solution. You should think about swapping algorithms if it really slows down your program.

Comment: You seem to have missed the "modulo" part. While Guava surely does `pow` right and efficiently, you may need to apply "mod" in every step. For the same reason `Math.pow` won't work.